# Overload resolution failed because no 'item' is accessible

Tags: .net, vb.net

I don't know why I am getting this error in my custom class

> Overload resolution failed because no 'item' is accessible" on line 15 and 16. To see the code follow the link

```
Imports System.Configuration

Public Class AppSettings 
  Private config As Configuration

  Public Sub AppSetting()
    config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
  End Sub

  Public Function GetConnectionString(ByVal key As String) As String
    Return config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings(key).ConnectionString
  End Function

  Public Sub SaveConnectionString(ByVal key As String, ByVal value As String)
    config.ConnectionStrings(key).ConnectionString = value
    config.ConnectionStrings(key).ProviderName = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
    config.Save(configurationSaveMode.Modified)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: These two line its where the errors appear config.ConnectionStrings(key).ConnectionString = value
config.ConnectionStrings(key).ProviderName = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient"

Comment: I don't know that class very well, but the ConnectionStrings property is not a collection or a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `.ConnectionStrings` between `config` and `.ConnectionStrings(key)` as you correctly have in your `GetConnectionString` method:

```
config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings(key).ConnectionString = value
config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings(key).ProviderName = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
```

But you could use a temporary variable to simplfy

```
Dim connString = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings(key)
connString.ConnectionString = value
connString.ProviderName = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
```

or using a `With` statement

```
With config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings(key)
    .ConnectionString = value
    .ProviderName = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
End With
```

Comment: now i have run into another problem. When i try to access "SaveConnectionString" method from another class i get this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" it points this line of code "With config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings(key)"

Comment: Dim saveSettings = New AppSettings 

saveSettings.SaveConnectionString("cn", conString)
 MessageBox.Show("Connection Settings saved Successfully!")

The above code is executed with button click event.Is this code wrong? if yes where am I missing

Comment: See: [Connection Strings and Configuration Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Examples are in C# but the procedure is the same in VB.